Can Fast Downward planner deal with conditional effects like 'when'?
I'm encountering an issue with a particular section of code.
This is the domain file:
(define (domain gripper-strips)
   (:predicates (room ?r)
        (ball ?b)
        (gripper ?g)
        (at-robby ?r)
        (at ?b ?r)
        (free ?g)
        (carry ?o ?g)
        (world )
        (dfa )
        (q1)(q2)(q3)(q4)
        
)
        
(:action dfaact
       :parameters  ()
       :precondition (and (dfa ))
       :effect (and  (not(dfa )) (world ) 
         (when (and  (q1) (at ball1 roomb) (not(at ball4 roomb)) ) 
                       (and (q3) (not (q1)))
         ) 
         (when (and  (q1) (at ball1 roomb) (at ball4 roomb))
                (and (q4) (not(q1)))
         )
         (when (and  (q1) (at ball4 roomb) (not(at ball1 roomb)))
               (and  (q2) (not(q1)))
         )
         (when (and  (q3) (at ball1 roomb) (at ball4 roomb))
               (and  (q4) (not(q3)))
         )
         (when (and  (q3) (not(at ball1 roomb)))
               (and  (q2) (not(q3)))
         )

        )
)


   (:action move
       :parameters  (?from ?to)
       :precondition (and  (room ?from) (room ?to) (at-robby ?from) (world ))
       :effect (and  (at-robby ?to)
             (not (at-robby ?from))  (not(world )) (dfa ) ))


   (:action pick
       :parameters (?obj ?room ?gripper)
       :precondition  (and  (ball ?obj) (room ?room) (gripper ?gripper)
                (at ?obj ?room) (at-robby ?room) (free ?gripper)(world ))
       :effect (and (carry ?obj ?gripper)
            (not (at ?obj ?room)) 
            (not (free ?gripper))(not(world )) (dfa )))


   (:action drop
       :parameters  (?obj  ?room ?gripper)
       :precondition  (and  (ball ?obj) (room ?room) (gripper ?gripper)
                (carry ?obj ?gripper) (at-robby ?room)(world ))
       :effect (and (at ?obj ?room)
            (free ?gripper)
            (not (carry ?obj ?gripper))(not(world )) (dfa ))))


And this is the problem file:
(define (problem strips-gripper-x-1)
   (:domain gripper-strips)
   (:objects rooma roomb ball4 ball3 ball2 ball1 left right)
   (:init (q1)
      (dfa)
      (room rooma)
          (room roomb)
          (ball ball4)
          (ball ball3)
          (ball ball2)
          (ball ball1)
          (at-robby rooma)
          (free left)
          (free right)
          (at ball4 rooma)
          (at ball3 rooma)
          (at ball2 rooma)
          (at ball1 rooma)
          (gripper left)
          (gripper right))
   (:goal (and (q4)
        (at ball4 roomb)
               (at ball3 roomb)
               (at ball2 roomb)
               (at ball1 roomb))))

Then I use this command to run it:
./fast-downward.py tests/gripper_ltlf/prob01.pddl --search "astar(lmcut())" 

And part of the error message is as follow:
"This configuration does not support conditional effects (operator dfaact)!  
Terminating.  
Tried to use unsupported feature.   
Peak memory: 23248 KB  
Remove intermediate file output.sas  
search exit code: 34"

I try to solve a pddl problem using Fast Downward planner, and in the code I use the word "when", but the information reminds that it does not support conditional effects (operator dfaact).
I doubt whether the search algorithm I used was wrong, but I just started to learn how to use it, so I still don't understand how to deal with it

It does support conditional effects, yes, but it looks like you’re using a configuration that doesn’t. Probably the heuristic choice. You can see which support conditional effects over here: https://www.fast-downward.org/Doc/Evaluator

Thanks a lot.I used this command to run it"./fast-downward.py tests/gripper_ltlf/prob01.pddl --search "astar(lmcut())"  ",and I also doubt whether the search algorithm I used was wrong, but I just started to learn how to use it, so I still don't understand how to deal with it.

I think I know what the problem is.I check out the Doc and know that lmcut() does not support conditional effects.
